# discord.py - How to automatically convert certain text to a value and ACTUALLY show it? (ex: {member_mention} = @user )

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm working on a welcome module. I want a user to be able to mention the member with {member_mention}. I've tried doing that, but it just sends " {member_mention}. " I want it to be converted to the user that joined the server. Is this possible and how can I perform this?  The welcome message is custom-made, so performing this is harder. Any help? Please and thanks. :)

NOTE: its not supposed to be member.mention or something like that, I want it to be CUSTOM for the value, I don't know if its possible, but I think it is.

( something to help make this question more explainable: You know those popular bots like dyno that have a custom welcome message like this? [image] When you enter that trigger in, it will automatically convert it to what you input. I want this to happen in my code. How can I do this? )

### Code

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
            try:
                with open("database\\database_main\\serverdb.json", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                    data = json.load(f)
                if str(member.guild.id) in data:
                    logera = data[str(member.guild.id)]['log_joinlogs']
                    if logera == 0:
                        with open("database\\database_main\\serverdb.json", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                            data = json.load(f)
                        if str(member.guild.id) in data:
                            isenabled = data[str(member.guild.id)]['logchlID']
                            if isenabled == 0:
                                return
                            else:
                                creation = member.created_at.strftime("%a %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p")
                                channelrs = bot.get_channel(data[str(member.guild.id)]['logchlID'])
                                embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Member Joined", color=discord.Colour.green())
                                embed.add_field(name="Account Creation Date", value=f"{creation}")
                                embed.set_footer(text=f"User ID: {member.id}")
                                embed.set_author(name=f"{member.display_name} (@{member.name})", icon_url=member.avatar)
                                await channelrs.send(embed=embed)
                    else:
                        return
            except:
                return
            with open("database\\database_main\\serverdb.json", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                datar = json.load(f)
                welcomemodule = datar[str(member.guild.id)]['welcome_module']
                if welcomemodule == 0:
                    welcomemessage = datar[str(member.guild.id)]['welcome_message']
                    if welcomemessage == "":
                        print("welcom message no?")
                        return
                    else:
                        welcoa = datar[str(member.guild.id)]['welcome_chl_id']
                        if welcoa == 0:
                            return
                        else:
                            member_mention = member.mention
                            welcomechl = bot.get_channel(datar[str(member.guild.id)]['welcome_chl_id'])
                            await welcomechl.send(f"{welcomemessage}")
```

### JSON file:

```
{
    "1141583283403116574": {
        "level_module": 0,
        "moderation_module": 0,
        "lvlupID": 1173294414303600771,
        "xpaddition": 0,
        "logchlID": 1161019161531662466,
        "log_joinlogs": 0,
        "log_leavelogs": 0,
        "log_banlogs": 1,
        "log_deletemsglogs": 0,
        "fun_module": 0,
        "log_editedmsglogs": 0,
        "welcome_module": 0,
        "welcome_message": "hi **{member_mention}!!!**",
        "svrid": "phmouGp",
        "welcome_chl_id": 1165505902841962588,
        "welcome_dm_message": "hi"
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you said which specific line of code is sending the message.  We're not all discord experts.

Comment: ``await welcomechl.send(f"{welcomemessage}")``

Comment: where do you have `{member_mention}.`?

Comment: ``member_mention = member.mention``, I want it to automatically mention the user, but it just shows {member_mention} and if I try member.mention it does the same thing

Comment: I means: where you have `{member_mention}` in some text message?

Comment: its custom made, a user can have ``{member_mention}`` in their message at any time, its stored in a JSON file, check edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply replacing the keywords with the corresponding values ​​using `str.replace()`??

```py
welcomemessage = datar[str(member.guild.id)]['welcome_message']
welcomemessage = welcomessage.replace("{member_mention}", member.mention)
```